# Saving values at exit of an application

Tags: android

I want to save the value of a string at exit of my application(process kill) in last activity , so that when I start that application again I can retrieve that value in first activity.

I tried the `sharedpreferences` but that does not solve my problem. Here is the code snippet.

```
     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     Intent int1 = getIntent();
     String pth  = prefs.getString("pathreturned", "true");
```

to retrieve in the first activity.

and this one to save it in the previous activity:

```
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
    e.putString("pathreturned", path);
    e.commit();
```

Comment: You are accessing a different settings file both times, see my answer.

Comment: actually there was a problem with some other part of the code! Problem solved now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your previous Activity, use the same code as the one you used before...

Instead of

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete Example of Saving Strings Via SharedPreferences

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button; 
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class SharedPrefs extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText dataInput;
private TextView dataView;
private SharedPreferences sharedString;
public static final String myFile = "MySharedDataFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sharedprefs);
    setUpVariables();
    sharedString = getSharedPreferences(myFile, 0);
}

public void setUpVariables(){
    dataInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dataToUse);
    dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showDataView);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savedataButton);
    Button load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadDataButton);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    load.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.savedataButton:
        String dataToSave = dataInput.getText().toString();
        Editor storeData = sharedString.edit();
        storeData.putString("key", dataToSave);
        storeData.commit();
        break;
    case R.id.loadDataButton:
        sharedString = getSharedPreferences(myFile, 0);
        String savedData = sharedString.getString("key", "No data Found");
        dataView.setText(savedData);
        break;
    }

}



 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know which Activity is going to be "last" you should save your value at the close of each activity. Override the onStop method and save it there.